# Unable to setup Environment variables seperately for prod and dev environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, environment-variables

I have my Node.js project having environment file setup like below

```
let config = {
  apiVersion: "/api/v1",
  PORT: 3001,
  mongodb: {
    url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/BTracker",
  },
};

module.exports = { config: config };
```

As i deploy my application , i need to change mongodb url and port fields as per my Prod URL.
How can i change these variables based on the environment?

Here is snippet of my index.js

```
let { config } = require("./app/config/appConfig");
app.listen(config.PORT, () => {
  mongoose.connect(config.mongodb.url, { useMongoClient: true });
  console.log("App is listening on " + config.PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create 2 `.env` file where you store all the configurations and keep it at the level of your index.js and make sure its not added in your git repository, one for the development and another for production.
Sample .env file for development:

```
#ENVIRONMENT
ENV="DEVELOPMENT"
#URI
MONGO_URI="mongodb://localhost:27017/BTracker"
```

Then in your index.js load this env file. You can use the [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) package to do that.
Code to load the env file.
The first line of your index.js should be this:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Then you can read all the keys from the env file using

```
const enviromentValue = process.env[KEY_VALUE];
```

For your code, you can use this:

```
let urlDB = process.env.MONGO_URI;
```

This will set the value of `urlDB="mongodb://localhost:27017/BTracker"`. You will need change the .env file according to your setup, whether you are in production or development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Set enviroment variables for configuration

```
process.env.PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'; 

let urlDB;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev') {
    urlDB = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/BTracker'
} else {
    urlDB = process.env.MONGO_URI;
}
process.env.URLDB = urlDB;
```

and for your index

```
require('./app/config/appConfig')
mongoose.connect(process.env.URLDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }, (err, res) => {
    console.log(process.env.URLDB);
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log();
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(App is listening on , process.env.PORT));
})
```